# Find the height of the water

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image: This the picture of the problem]

Seemingly easy, but I have some doubts that I did something wrong. My answer is 5.5 m.

Comment: Can you show your work?  Your instructor won;t care about whether you got the actual answer ... it';s how you got to it.

Comment: And yes, without using a calculator I can already tell something is wrong: From low to high tide is about 6 hours, so a full period from low to high to low takes about 12 hours. So, since it was low tide at 2am, it'll be low tide at about 2pm as well, and a quarter of the period in, i.e. 3 hours after that, i.e. at about 5pm, the water should be at the average level, which should be at $(12.4+1.2)/2=6.8m$
. So, a little after 5, it should be close to 7m. In fact, this is the time the water rises most quickly, so probably close to 8m. Wherever it exactly is, your 5.5m is definitely too low.